# Как убрать зеленое поле в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Пример зеленого поля на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а это точно не выделение?

Comment: Больше похоже на подсветку кода во время дебага

Comment: 1. Нет, это не выделение.

2. При написании кода появилось всплывающее окно, с текстом типа "показать дублирующий код?" - я нажал "показать". Весь блок кода, который имеет в другом месте аналогичный код, выделился вот таким зеленым полем. Долго искал варианты, как убрать это выделение. Не нашел. Вылечилось - перезагрузкой IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажмите клавишу escape на клавиатуре.
Понимаю, что ответ возможно и не нужен, но оставлю для будущих поколений так сказать)))